# A schizophrenics experiment from Bayesian Data Analysis, Gelman et al textbook

Tags: regression, mixed-model, anova, generalized-linear-model, data-transformation

There is a psychology experiment in the [Gelman et al textbook](http://chrome-extension://efaidnbmnnnibpcajpcglclefindmkaj/viewer.html?pdfurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stat.columbia.edu%2F%7Egelman%2Fbook%2FBDA3.pdf&clen=66473875&chunk=true) on page 524 *section 22.2 Example: reaction times and schizophrenia*, I believe the original work is from [Belin and Rubin (1990)](http://chrome-extension://efaidnbmnnnibpcajpcglclefindmkaj/viewer.html?pdfurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stat.columbia.edu%2F%7Egelman%2Fresearch%2Fpublished%2Fitsim.pdf&clen=7291836&chunk=true) where the authors illustrated simple mixture models with this [dataset](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/%7Egelman/book/data/schiz.asc) containing 17 people: 11 non-schizophrenics and 6 schizophrenics had their reaction times measured 30 times.

I am limited in Mixture Models and all the alternative models the authors prescribed. So far, I have prior knowledge on Regression, ANOVA, Nested models, Categorical Predictions and Interactions, Model Diagnostic, Collinearity, Transformation, Variable Selection etc. and I would like to accurately tackle the prompt question:

*Are there meaningful differences in reaction times between the schizophrenic and
non-schizophrenic patients, adjusting for correlation between patients' repeated measurements?*

How and what is the best way of formulating appropriate model(s) to answer the prompt question. Please, forgive me of my ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

A simple extension of regression and ANOVA is the general linear model for correlated data.  Rather than having a single scalar variance term paired with an identity matrix as in a typical regression, the covariance matrix is a block diagonal.  The off-diagonal elements in each block account for the correlation between repeated measurements on subjects.  This modeling approach can be further generalized a la generalized estimating equations.  During inference one can use the model-based covariance matrix of the parameter estimates, or instead opt for the empirical sandwich covariance matrix estimator.  The latter is robust to misspecification of the model variance.  I suggest reading the documentation on SAS Proc Genmod and Proc Glimmix, even if you do not plan on using SAS or these particular procedures.  The documentation contains a wealth of knowledge, https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.4/statug/statug_genmod_details29.htm.  If you prefer working in R I think the relevant package would be glm.